# ioctl IOCGIWSCAN : invalid arguments,

Tags: c, ioctl, iwconfig

Hi everybody i'm trying to get information so does iwlist command. 
I got a invalid arguments errno, and I don't understand why, I'm fellowing a good paper with deals about that : 
[ioctl & iwreq](http://blog.listincomprehension.com/2011/03/wireless-scanning-with-erlang.html)
.
My code is the fellowing :

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netpacket/packet.h>
#include <netinet/if_ether.h>
#include "ioctlcmd.h"
#include <arpa/inet.h>

/*  SIOCGIWNAME     0x8B01  power
    SIOCGIWTXPOW    0x8B27  
    SIOCSIWFREQ     0x8B04        set channel/frequency (Hz)   
*/



int check_ifname_exist(char * ifname) {

    int sock = socket(AF_PACKET,SOCK_RAW,0) ; 
    if (sock == RET_ERR) {
      printf("Error while checking ifname [ERRNO : %d], [STRERROR : %s]\n",errno,strerror(errno)); 
      return RET_ERR ; 
    }   

    struct ifreq ifr ; 
    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name,ifname,IFNAMSIZ) ;

    int ret = ioctl(sock,SIOCGIFINDEX,&ifr) ; 
    if (ret == RET_ERR) {
      printf("Error while checking ifname [ERRNO : %d], [STRERROR : %s]\n",errno,strerror(errno)); 
      return RET_ERR ; 
    }

   return RET_SUCCES ; 
}

int get_channel_fq(char * essid, char * ifname) {

  int sock = socket(AF_PACKET,SOCK_RAW,0) ; 
  if (sock == RET_ERR) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error while opening socket [ERRNO : %d] [STRERROR : %s]\n",errno,strerror(errno)); 
    return RET_ERR ;    
  }

  if (bind_socket(ifname,sock) == RET_ERR)
    return RET_ERR ; 
  printf("coucou\n") ; //DEBUG 
  struct iwreq iwr ; 
  memset(&iwr,0,sizeof(struct iwreq)) ; 
  memcpy(iwr.ifr_ifrn.ifrn_name,ifname,IFNAMSIZ) ;
  printf("%s\n",iwr.ifr_ifrn.ifrn_name) ;   
  iwr.u.data.pointer = essid ; 
  iwr.u.data.length = strlen(essid)+1 ; 
  iwr.u.data.flags |= IW_SCAN_THIS_ESSID ; 

  if ((sock =ioctl(sock,SIOCSIWSCAN,&iwr)) == RET_ERR) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error while getting the freq of the card. [ERRNO : %d] [STRERROR : %s]\n",errno,strerror(errno)) ; 
    return RET_ERR ; 
  }
  printf("coucou\n") ;  // DEBUG
  int bufsize = 4096 ;
  struct iwreq iwr2 ={0} ; 
  //memset(&iwr2,0,sizeof(struct iwreq)) ; 
  char  *p = NULL ; 
  p=calloc(bufsize,1) ; 
  iwr2.u.data.pointer = p ; 
  iwr2.u.data.length = bufsize ; 
  iwr2.u.data.flags = 0 ;
  memcpy(iwr2.ifr_ifrn.ifrn_name,ifname,IFNAMSIZ) ;
  if (ioctl(sock,SIOCGIWSCAN,&iwr2) == RET_ERR) { // ERROR 
         fprintf(stderr,"Error while getting the freq of the card. [ERRNO : %d] [STRERROR : %s]\n",errno,strerror(errno)) ; // ERROR IS HERE
         return RET_ERR ;
  }

   return RET_SUCCES ; 
}

int bind_socket(char * ifname,int sock_fd) {

  struct ifreq ifr ; 
  struct sockaddr_ll sall ; 
  memset(&sall,0,sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll)) ; 
  strncpy(ifr.ifr_name,ifname,IFNAMSIZ) ; 
  ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_INET ; 

  if (ioctl(sock_fd,SIOCGIFINDEX,&ifr) == RET_ERR) 
    goto ret_err ; 
  if (ifr.ifr_ifindex < 0) 
     goto ret_err ; 

  sall.sll_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex  ; 
  sall.sll_family = AF_PACKET ; 
  sall.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_ALL) ; 

  if (bind(sock_fd,(struct sockaddr *)&sall,sizeof(sall)) == RET_ERR) 
    goto ret_err ;

  return sock_fd ; 

ret_err : 

   fprintf(stderr,"Error while binding socket. [ERRNO = %d] [STDERROR = %s]\n",errno,strerror(errno)) ; 
   return RET_ERR ; 
}

int main() {

   get_channel_fq("ditwifi","wlan0") ; 
}
```

In the code above, the two printf("coucou") are printed, so I'm sure that the first ioctl()
     ioctl(sock,IOCSIWSCAN,&iwr)
works fine.

I think I miss something, but I did't find.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Of course, "ditwifi" and "wlan0" exist.

Answer (score 0):

The iwreq structure must point to a buffer large enough to hold the response (the list of APs).